# python dictionary array of callbacks with types

Tags: python, typing

Is there anyway to do what I want below? Below is invalid syntax, but I can't seem to figure it out. I want a dict of callback names with their structure as value

```
from typing import Callable, List


callbacks = {
    "foo1": List[Callable[arg_name: int], None]: [],
    "foo2": List[Callable[arg_name: int, arg_name2: int], None]: [],
}
```

Comment: still looking thx

Answer (score 0):

You can’t give a different type to each element in a dictionnary for the following reason

**The amount / names of dictionary keys isn’t supposed to be known ahead**. It is a dynamic type. Thus **you cannot statically type its elements, since they aren’t statically known**

If you want a data structure where you know by advance what fields are going to be used, you should use another one such as

- A class (or a dataclass)
- A named tuple

What you can do:

### 1. If you expect to get more elements in your dictionary that you do not know about

```py
from typing import Callable, List

callbacks : dict[str, list[Callable]] = {
    "foo1": [],
    "foo2": [],
}
```

### 2. If you know all the elements in the dictionary

If you only have foo1 and foo2, you could use a dataclass instead to have more granular typechecking

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field 
from typing import Callable, List

@dataclass
class Callbacks():
    foo1: List[Callable[arg_name: int], None] =  field(default_factory=list)
    foo2: List[Callable[arg_name: int, arg_name2: int], None]  = field(default_factory=list)

callbacks = Callbacks()
```

and if you need to refer to an element by name, you can always use `getattr`